# Trying to populate ArrayList with user input with methods

Tags: java

I am trying to populate my array with user input; however, I cannot get it to properly work. I am trying to get an int for the user for the number of products they want to enter. Then I want to populate the array with more user input of actual products (Strings) based on the number of products they said they wanted to enter. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Practice {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bannerPrinter();
        getNum();
        int num = 0;
        ArrayList<String> products = productBuilder(num);
        boolean productGuess = getOrder(products);
        if (productGuess) {
            double price = getPrice();
            double tax = getTax(price);
            double total = getTotal(tax, price);
            printTotal(total);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Product not found.");
        }
    }

    public static void bannerPrinter() {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("******************************************");
        System.out.println("****** Welcome to my eCommerce app! ******");
        System.out.println("******************************************");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int getNum() {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of products: ");
        num = scnr.nextInt();

        return num;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> productBuilder(int num) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String arrayNames = "";
        ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the products: ");
            products.add(arrayNames);
        }
        return products;
    }

    public static boolean getOrder(ArrayList<String> products) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String guess = "";

        boolean productName = products.contains(guess);

        System.out.print("Enter a product: ");
        guess = scnr.nextLine();

        if(productName) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("This product has been found.");
            System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println();
        }

        return productName;
    }

    public static double getPrice() {

        double price = 0.0;
        price = (int)(Math.random() * 100);

        return price;
    }

    public static double getTax(double price) {

        double tax = 0.0;
        tax = price * 0.10;

        return tax;
    }

    public static double getTotal(double price, double tax) {

        double saleTotal = 0.0;
        saleTotal = price + tax;

        return saleTotal;
    }

    public static void printTotal(double saleTotal) {

        System.out.println("You total is $" + saleTotal + "0");
    }

}
```

Comment: *Interesting... At my university, we currently have semester projects which are about e-commerce. If this sounds like you, then I wonder if we know each other by any chance.*

Comment: Not quite clear as to what you want to do after you take the user's inputs. Please give an example.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @intboolstring, touche.

Comment: I would like the user to enter a number (the number of products that they wish to enter into the list), then after that I would like them to also enter the different products that they want in the ArrayList. But I would like the program to stop asking for products when it reaches the number value that the user entered before

Comment: for example, if the user enters that they would like to enter 2 products, the program allows them to enter two products (apples and peaches for example) and then it does the rest of the program

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand what you attempt to do but I did see some interesting lines... see my comments

```
public static ArrayList<String> productBuilder(int num) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String arrayNames = "";
    ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the products: ");
        // I assume here scnr is supposed to read something
        // and assign it to arrayNames?
        products.add(arrayNames);
    }
    return products;
}

public static boolean getOrder(ArrayList<String> products) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess = "";

    // I assume this line is supposed to be after
    //    guess = scnr.nextLine()?
    boolean productName = products.contains(guess); // very confusing line

    System.out.print("Enter a product: ");
    guess = scnr.nextLine();

    if(productName) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("This product has been found.");
        System.out.println();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println();
    }

    return productName;
}
```